VBA Code Works for Me But Not My Colleague on Chart Object Scaling
I have a part of a much larger code that essentially runs the following process.

Excel Screen Zoom in from 100% to 200%
Make a bunch of tables and charts in the Excel document into Chart Objects
Exports those chart objects at that zoom size (effectively doubling them from the original)
Zooms back to normal 100% when complete.

The whole code works as expected for me. It will successfully double the size of the images that I export. Thus, I don't think its primarily the codes fault that my colleague is not able to run it fully. However, when I hand it off to my colleague it doesn't work. The rest of the code runs fine for him, it just does not do the image rescaling using screen zoom in. I can solve the problem in other ways in vba as there are other ways to rescale images, but I preferred this one as it made the pictures better and didn't really change anything about how they looked other than they were bigger.
For reference, I've included the imagine rescaling feature of the code and how I'm exporting chart objects.
'This chunk of code essentially controls a Scaling Factor so that we can control should pictures be normal, 2x? 3x?
'Note this code doesn't affect table size just bar chart size.

Workbooks("Twenty Year Graphs and Data.xlsx").Activate
Dim wsh As Worksheet
For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
wsh.Activate
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
Next wsh


'This chunk of code creates seperate chart objects for each graph and exports them

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Dim CAC As ChartObject
Dim ASHP As ChartObject
Dim CACASHP As ChartObject
Dim CGSWH As ChartObject
Dim CESWH As ChartObject
Dim CSWH As ChartObject
Dim RGASWH As ChartObject
Dim REASWH As ChartObject
Dim RASWH As ChartObject
Dim GWAF As ChartObject
Dim OWAF As ChartObject
Dim Furnaces As ChartObject


Set CAC = Sheets("CAC and ASHP").ChartObjects("CAC")
Set ASHP = Sheets("CAC and ASHP").ChartObjects("ASHP")
Set CACASHP = Sheets("CAC and ASHP").ChartObjects("CAC & ASHP")
Set CGSWH = Sheets("CSWH").ChartObjects("CGSWH")
Set CESWH = Sheets("CSWH").ChartObjects("CESWH")
Set CSWH = Sheets("CSWH").ChartObjects("CSWH")
Set RGASWH = Sheets("RSWH").ChartObjects("RGASWH")
Set REASWH = Sheets("RSWH").ChartObjects("REASWH")
Set RASWH = Sheets("RSWH").ChartObjects("RASWH")
Set GWAF = Sheets("Furnaces").ChartObjects("GWAF")
Set OWAF = Sheets("Furnaces").ChartObjects("OWAF")
Set Furnaces = Sheets("Furnaces").ChartObjects("Furnaces")
CAC.Activate
ActiveChart.Export "\\EgnyteDrive\ahri\Shared\AHRI General Share (AllShare)\Data Services\Statistics\AHRI Website Content\AHRI Website Yearly Public Historical Data\" & TwentyYears & "-" & LastYear & " Historical Data\" & "Central Air Conditioners Chart" & ".jpg"

Haven't tried too much because I haven't been able to identify if it was a Windows/Excel setting or something else causing it. Tried enabling and disabling the developer tab on colleagues machine. This didn't work.
We have the same overall Windows 11 settings and Excel settings so we are operating by enlarge on the same version of Excel.
There are different display settings on our machines.

Does the screen zoom change on your colleague's computer?

Screen zoom does change on my colleague's computer. We also tested it today and we have the same display settings.  My computer still doubles the picture size and his does not.

On the test today Excel did something weird on his computer that it didn't do on mine. For his computer it actually moved all the pictures in the sheet to some cell I didn't specify and didn't zoom them as it zoomed the rest of the document. In this case, it kept them at 100% when the Zoomed sheet was at 200%. On mine it worked perfect.
